# get public only events (V3)

Tags: google-api

I V3 events list API, I can't see how can I filter the list to get only the public events.
Currently I'm getting all events, the private ones are just specified as private ("visibility":"private"). 
But I couldn't find a way to filter by visibility.
Does someone know how to assist here?